# Understanding the interaction between the chaincode / peer and the local copy of the ledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

**question 1:**

The chaincode (`hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/examplexx/chaincode.go`) accesses the ledger via the `ChaincodeStubInterface`, e.g. `stub.GetState(.)`, `stub.PutState(.)`.

`ChaincodeStubInterface` is implemented by `hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/chaincode.go`.

If I see it correctly, the `stub`used for `PutState`and `GetState`gets created by `handleInit(.)` of `hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/handler.go`:

`stub := new(ChaincodeStub)`

`handleInit` is called by `handleReady` which is called by `handleMessage` which is called by `chatWithPeer` which is called by `Start` (`hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/chaincode.go`) which is called by the `main` function of `hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/examplexx/cmd/main.go`

a) With which command does this `main` function get invoked? By `$peer chaincode install`?

b) And where in the fabric code gets this `main`function then called (I would be glad about some pointers).

**question 2:**

Assume `$peer chaincode invoke .. '{"Args":["yy","a","b","10"]}'` calls the `yy`transaction method in the `chaincode.go` (`hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/examplexx/chaincode.go`) file. Assume this transaction excutes a `stub.GetState(.)` which calls `stub.handler.handleGetState(.)`.

a) Is this Handler kind of an intermediate between the chaincode and the peer/ledger?

b) Does a handler belong to a peer? If yes, is there one handler per peer or are there multiple handlers (one for each chaincode)?

c) When does this Handler get instantiated?

d) When does the local ledger copy for the peer gets instantiated?

I know these are lots of questions. But I would be very glad about some hints so that I can figure out how the local copy of the ledger gets created and how the chaincode / peer communicates with it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a) With which command does this main function get invoked? By $peer
>   chaincode install?
>
> b) And where in the fabric code gets this mainfunction then called (I
>   would be glad about some pointers).

The main function is defined in the peer code. When the peer decides to run the chaincode container, it just runs a docker image of the chaincode shim (golang,java,node.js) and just runs the command [according to the chaincode language](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/core/chaincode/container_runtime.go#L164-L170).

```
    switch ccType {
    case pb.ChaincodeSpec_GOLANG.String(), pb.ChaincodeSpec_CAR.String():
        lc.Args = []string{"chaincode", fmt.Sprintf("-peer.address=%s", c.PeerAddress)}
    case pb.ChaincodeSpec_JAVA.String():
        lc.Args = []string{"/root/chaincode-java/start", "--peerAddress", c.PeerAddress}
    case pb.ChaincodeSpec_NODE.String():
        lc.Args = []string{"/bin/sh", "-c", fmt.Sprintf("cd /usr/local/src; npm start -- --peer.address %s", c.PeerAddress)}
default:
```

> a) Is this Handler kind of an intermediate between the chaincode and
>   the peer/ledger?
>
> b) Does a handler belong to a peer? If yes, is there one handler per
>   peer or are there multiple handlers (one for each chaincode)?
>
> c) When does this Handler get instantiated?
>
> d) When does the local ledger copy for the peer gets instantiated?

No, the the GetState actually calls a function on the local chaincode shim, not on the peer. Then, the chaincode shim (running in its container) sends a message to the peer via a dedicated gRPC stream, and the peer then reads from the database the value for the key, and returns the result to the chaincode shim, by sending it back to the gRPC stream, where the chaincode shim waits for the result.

As for handlers - there is a [handler](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/core/chaincode/handler.go) on the peer, for each chaincode.

Now, this all takes care during the endorsement time (computation of the chaincode) - but the local database is never updated during endorsement. 
When the chaincode execution is finished, the client sends the transaction to the orderer, and then the orderer makes a new block and writes it to its filesystem.

The peer then pulls the block, checks the signature (from the endorsement) of the peer that executed the chaincode, and if the signature is valid then it updates its local database.

Comment: So for a `stub.GetState(.)` the [handler on the shim side of the chaincode](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/core/chaincode/shim/handler.go/#L304) does `handleGetState`-> `callPeerWithChaincodeMsg` -> `sendReceive` -> `serialSendAsync` -> `serialSend`-> `Send`. If I have understood correctly, this `Send` would make a gRPC call to the [handler on the peer side](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/core/chaincode/handler.go). Could you send me a pointer to the code snippet, where the peer handler is listening for the `GetState`?

Comment: And for the local ledger: The [handler on the peer side of the chaincode stream](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/core/chaincode/handler.go) has access to a  [PeerLedger](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/core/ledger/ledger_interface.go). I assume that this PeerLedger gets initialized at the start of the peer `$peer node start...`. But I cannot figure out the where exactly in [start.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/peer/node/start.go#L176) this happens?

Comment: this is too complex to answer on stackoverflow :/ come to https://chat.hyperledger.org/ and ask there.

Comment: I will do that.